# Query with Variable not estimating right

Tags: sql-server, performance, execution-plan, cardinality-estimates

I have a query with several joins that is not performing well. After a lot of triage, I decided to take the query apart and look at just the driving table. Below is an example of the query based on just the driving table.

```
DECLARE @VAR AS INT

SET @VAR = 11652862

SELECT Field1, Field2
FROM tablea
WHERE Field2 = @VAR
```

When I run the code as it is the actual execution plan comes back with 15k estimated rows and 1m actual rows. Yes, this is just a simple `SELECT...FROM TABLE`, but remember this is just part of a bigger query, so this estimate difference greatly compounds as we add more joins.

I know the problem is the `@VAR` because the optimizer does not know the value of the variable when it compiles the query into a plan so its coming back with the avg # of rows for the estimate for the field. If I add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` it will force in the value when it compiles and come back with the correct # of rows.

Here is the kicker: This is not custom code that my company can edit. It is part of a third party app that I cannot edit. Updating stats will not help (I looked at the histogram and it is correctly listing the value for my variable). I already have a covering NC index on those two fields. The only option I can think of is to use a forced execution plan on this query. I have never been able to successfully do that, though. Anyone have any other ideas or a good How-To reference on forced execution plans?

Since it was asked in the comments, the create statement for the index is:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx ON tablea (Field2)
```

Comment: Can you post the query plan?  Do you have an index on Field2?  If so, what is the definition?

Comment: I know you said you can't change the code here, but for general reference: in this situation I've found it helpful to stage the results in a temp table (e.g., just storing `Field1`) so that the sproc gets accurate counts for subsequent steps.

Comment: @ChadMattox The plan is located here (I had to manually edit the xml to remove the actual table names, let me know if it doesn't display correctly): https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJOJoVaA. And I have updated the post to include the index def.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades Yes, if I had access to the code there are many options I can think of to fix this.

Comment: Not sure if this is part of your question, but when a local variable is used (like above) SQL doesn't use the histogram, it uses the density * rows to estimate cardinality, unless you recompile. Plan guides are hell. Have you opened a ticket with the vendor yet?

Comment: @ChadMattox if it weren't covering the plan would likely show a key lookup.

Comment: You said actual no of rows is 1 million. Because your query is SELECT statement so it includes rendering also. Can you please confirm if rendering is not taking time?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik Not yet, that was going to be my next course if there was no other option.

Comment: @AshwiniMohan Again, this is just the query for the driving table. The actual full query returns ZERO records :). Yet it was running for over an hour and half by the time I killed it because the plan sucks so bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have other ideas than a plan guide and I'll post them here for your consideration, but I cannot recommend actually implementing them. There are at least two different ways of bumping up row estimates from tablea. The first involves manually setting statistics and the second involves redirecting the third party app to use a view that you defined instead of accessing the tablea directly.

Both CREATE STATISTICS and UPDATE STATISTICS have a STATS_STREAM option. Here is what Books Online says about it:

> Identified for informational purposes only. Not supported. Future compatibility is not guaranteed.

It's completely understandable if that turns you off from using it, but what it allows you to do is to transplant the statistics from one object to another. Suppose that you want to increase cardinality estimates from queries that use tablea by 50X. You could take the data from tablea, duplicate it 50 times, gather stats with FULLSCAN, then update the statistics on tablea using the STATS_STREAM value from the other table along with the NORECOMPUTE option. You probably want to change the ROWCOUNT value as well. This should have a pretty large effect on all queries that reference the table. You could run into problems with other queries, with the underlying data changing in the table, with statistics on indexes not getting updated, and so on. This isn't a good option.

Depending on how the third party application connects to SQL Server, you may be able to create a view with a different schema from tablea and to direct that part of the application to use in the view. The view should have all of the same columns as tablea but should have additional code which inflates the number of rows returned. I didn't try that hard to get this to work because it seems very impractical, but this approach was inspired by Adam Machanic's article about [forcing parallel plans](http://dataeducation.com/next-level-parallel-plan-forcing-an-alternative-to-8649/):

```
SELECT ta.*
FROM tablea ta
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT t.t
    FROM
    ( 
    VALUES 
    (2), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), 
    (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), 
    -- lots more values here ...
    (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)
   ) t(t)
WHERE t % 2 = 0
) t
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 8690);
```

I wasn't really satisfied with that query but didn't spend too much time on it. In that form it does a single scan of the table but the query optimizer overestimates the cardinality estimate by 100X. TF 8690 is there to prevent a pointless table spool, but this probably isn't appropriate in a view or in a larger query. If the same application inserts data into this table you'd need to deal with that somehow. This isn't a good option.

To reiterate, I don't think that you should attempt either of these options. It would be much better to talk to the vendor, or if that doesn't work, to suck it up and try again with a plan guide. I don't have any experience with those so I can't be of help.

Comment: Thanks for the additional ideas. I agree I don't like those alternatives either. I will reach out to the vendor and in the meantime try the plan guides again.